# The way of script Photoshop Neutral Filter?

Tags: photoshop-script, photoshop-sdk

I believe by using photoshop API we can access to few functionalities or actions in photoshop!
are there way to access Neutral filter?

I am using Nodejs to connect my DropBox and photoshop API and making some simple actions! like Straiting... Hope there are away to access Neutral filter and automate it ?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via ActionJSON (https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/photoshop-api-docs/features/#actionjson). You would record it, and then use it with the API to apply the filter to other images.